# Group by hour, then sort properly (22-23-0-1-2 ...)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I'm trying to group and sort a query by hour (24h format)

I want to retreive all rows from the last 12 hours, then group by hour, then sort them properly (11pm-12pm-1am-2pm = 22-23-1-2).

I get some result, but i have an issue when switch to 12pm (23) to 1am. See below :
Query :

```
    SELECT Count(*) AS AlertCount,
    HOUR(alert_timeraised) AS AlertHour
    FROM aggregate_alerts 
    WHERE alert_timeraised > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 HOUR)
    GROUP BY AlertHour
```

Result :

```
AlertCount  AlertHour

"12"    "0"
"15"    "1"
"40"    "2"
"14"    "3"
"52"    "4"
"16"    "5"
"58"    "6"
"23"    "7"
"61"    "8"
"92"    "9"
"96"    "10"
"15"    "11"
"15"    "23"
```

As you see 23 is last result, but i should be first (23/previousday-1-2-3-4/currentday ...)
If you have any idea to deal with this ...

FYI the initial timestamp format for alert_timeraised is :

2019-07-23 11:13:46
2019-07-22 23:20:29

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I advise that you provide a dbfiddle demo link with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this working :

```
SELECT Count(*) AS AlertCount,
   DATE_FORMAT(alert_timeraised, '%d.%m-%H:00') AS Date
    FROM aggregate_alerts
    WHERE alert_timeraised > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 HOUR)
    GROUP BY HOUR(alert_timeraised)
    ORDER BY DATE
```

Output :

```
"7"     "22-07 - 23h"
"12"    "23-07 - 00h"
"15"    "23-07 - 01h"
"40"    "23-07 - 02h"
"14"    "23-07 - 03h"
"52"    "23-07 - 04h"
"16"    "23-07 - 05h"
"58"    "23-07 - 06h"
"23"    "23-07 - 07h"
"61"    "23-07 - 08h"
"84"    "23-07 - 09h"
"89"    "23-07 - 10h"
"87"    "23-07 - 11h"
```

So it sort by date, but first with day, then hour.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try to group and then order by all different parts (YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR) of alert_timeraised

```
SELECT Count(*) AS AlertCount,
YEAR(alert_timeraised) as YEAR,
MONTH(alert_timeraised) as MONTH,
DAY(alert_timeraised) as DAY,
HOUR(alert_timeraised) AS AlertHour
FROM 
( 
select   '2019-07-23 11:13:46' as alert_timeraised union all
select   '2019-07-22 23:20:29' as alert_timeraised   
) t

#WHERE alert_timeraised > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 HOUR)
GROUP BY 
YEAR(alert_timeraised),
MONTH(alert_timeraised),
DAY(alert_timeraised),
HOUR(alert_timeraised)

order by 
YEAR(alert_timeraised),
MONTH(alert_timeraised),
DAY(alert_timeraised),
HOUR(alert_timeraised)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a date range resides in different Month or Year, You need to consider all scenario like year, month, day and hour as shown below-

```
SELECT 
YEAR(alert_timeraised),
MONTH(alert_timeraised),
DAY(alert_timeraised),
HOUR(alert_timeraised),
COUNT(*)

FROM aggregate_alerts 

GROUP BY    
YEAR(alert_timeraised),
MONTH(alert_timeraised),
DAY(alert_timeraised),
HOUR(alert_timeraised)

ORDER BY 
YEAR(alert_timeraised),
MONTH(alert_timeraised),
DAY(alert_timeraised),
HOUR(alert_timeraised);
```